# Git push is not working showing invalid username and password

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I changed my password for my GitHub account and after that, I am not able to clone or push anything from my VS code to GitHub. It shows an Invalid username or password. Can someone tell me how to resolve this error?

Comment: GitHub doesn't use passwords for Git clone/push.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.